# Portion of code (VBA) being skipped

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have a custom application developed in and for MS Project.  As it's executing one of its functions it's skipping over a portion of code resulting in an incorrect output.  Below is the line of code causing the error and forcing the application to skip ahead. Anyone know what could be causing it?

```
FilterEdit Name:="fCriteria", TaskFilter:=True, Create:=True, _
    OverwriteExisting:=True, FieldName:="Flag20", test:="equals", _
    Value:="No", ShowInMenu:=False, ShowSummaryTasks:=True
```

Here is the entire sub routine

```
If keepCriteriaCount > 0 And globRemProducts = True Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     WindowActivate WindowName:=globNewWindow
     TableApply Name:="Master Template"
 FilterApply Name:="All Tasks"
 Application.SetAutoFilter FieldName:="Flag20", FilterType:=pjAutoFilterClear

   SelectSheet
    SetTaskField Field:="Flag20", Value:="No"
    SelectTaskField Row:=0, Column:="Flag20", Height:=0
    EditCopy
    SelectTaskColumn Column:="Flag20"
    FillDown

            keepCriteriaArray() = Split(keepCriteria, ",")
            fCount = 0

            'Remove Tasks for excluded Products

                    For dCriteria = LBound(keepCriteriaArray) To UBound(keepCriteriaArray)
                        If Not keepCriteriaArray(dCriteria) = "" Then
                            If Len(Trim(keepCriteriaArray(dCriteria))) = 2 Then
                                projChannels = Trim(keepCriteriaArray(dCriteria)) & ","
                            Else
                                projChannels = Trim(keepCriteriaArray(dCriteria))
                            End If
                            If fCount = 0 Then
                                FilterEdit Name:="fCriteria", TaskFilter:=True, Create:=True, OverwriteExisting:=True, FieldName:="Text24", test:="contains", Value:=projChannels, ShowInMenu:=False, ShowSummaryTasks:=False
                                FilterEdit Name:="fCriteria", TaskFilter:=True, FieldName:="", NewFieldName:="Text24", test:="contains", Value:="All", Operation:="OR", ShowSummaryTasks:=False
                                fCount = fCount + 1
                            Else
                                projChannels = Trim(keepCriteriaArray(dCriteria))
                                FilterEdit Name:="fCriteria", TaskFilter:=True, FieldName:="", NewFieldName:="Text24", test:="contains", Value:=projChannels, Operation:="OR", ShowSummaryTasks:=False
                            End If
                        End If


                    Next dCriteria

            FilterApply Name:="fCriteria" ' apply the filter
            SelectSheet
            tCount = ActiveSelection.Tasks.Count
                SelectSheet
                SetTaskField Field:="Flag20", Value:="Yes"
                SelectTaskField Row:=0, Column:="Flag20", Height:=0
                EditCopy
                SelectTaskColumn Column:="Flag20"
                FillDown
             FilterApply Name:="All Tasks"
             Application.SetAutoFilter FieldName:="Flag20", FilterType:=pjAutoFilterClear
              If addCriteriaCount = 0 Then
                    tCriteria = projChannels & "; " & globStoreChannels & "; " & txtCustType.Value
                Else
                    tCriteria = addCriteria & ", " & projChannels & "; " & globStoreChannels & "; " & txtCustType.Value
                End If
    'WindowActivate WindowName:=globNewWindow


    TableApply Name:="Master Template"
    tskHeaderRow = 1


    SelectTaskField Row:=tskHeaderRow, Column:="Text4"
    SetTaskField Field:="Text4", Value:=tCriteria

             'before you delete - outdent all tasks
             SelectSheet

            For rLevel = ActiveSelection.Tasks.Count To 1 Step -1

                    SelectTaskField Row:=rLevel, Column:="Name", RowRelative:=False
                    OutlineOutdent
                    OutlineOutdent
                    OutlineOutdent
                    OutlineOutdent
            Next rLevel

                'If Not ActiveProject.AutoFilter Then Application.AutoFilter
                'Group
                On Error Resume Next
                'Application.SetAutoFilter FieldName:="Flag20", FilterType:=pjAutoFilterCustom, Test1:="contains", Criteria1:="No"
                FilterEdit Name:="fCriteria", TaskFilter:=True, Create:=True, OverwriteExisting:=True, FieldName:="Flag20", test:="equals", Value:="No", ShowInMenu:=False, ShowSummaryTasks:=True
                FilterApply Name:="fCriteria" ' apply the filter
                SelectSheet
                On Error GoTo removeErr
                If ActiveSelection.Tasks.Count >= 1 Then

                    SelectSheet
                        EditDelete

                End If
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with MS Project, but I have lots of coding experience. Usually, for something like "skipping", it's important to see more context (more code). You can use the [edit] link below the question to add more code.

Comment: when you say skipped, does this mean you have some error trapping saying that is the way or does it debug and you move it on?

Comment: there is a line of code written in if there's an error it will send it down to the next routine

Comment: Protip: Select the code from the VBE, hit [TAB] to **add 4 leading spaces to the entire block**, ***and then*** copy it; hit [Shift]+[TAB] to remove the spaces from your IDE, then [edit] your post, and paste the code you copied with the 4 leading spaces - Stack Exchange posts use markdown, and markdown requires 4 leading spaces for a code block. Doing that will always make your Stack Overflow code blocks look just like they look in your IDE.

Comment: remove `on error resume next` for a minute, restart the code, what error do you get? start from there...

Comment: FWIW: the FilterEdit statement is syntactically correct. As others have suggested, comment out the `On Error Resume Next` line and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be as helpful as you hoped... sorry...

The reason it is being "skipped over" is because of the way you are doing your error handling. `On Error Resume Next` is masking all relevant information. Now, you can make your program give you more information here, by adding things like `Debug.Print err.number: Debug.Print err.description` directly after the offensive line, but that will just put your error into the log. And it will only help you with one line, even though you have multiple lines inside your 'error ignoring section'. All of this is fine if you are watching your log at all times, but when I am using Project I rarely have the time to mess with that. I assume you are the same.

Now, if I had to guess the issue (don't have Project installed on my current machine, none of my current contracts want me using Gannt charts. I know, you should pity me), I think I recall that `Create:=True, OverwriteExisting:=True` are redundant, and you can remove the overwrite part just in case the fCriteria is still being used even after All Tasks was applied. Or, maybe instead of editing and overwriting the same filter, make fCriteria1, fCriteria2, etc. You can still copy filters as you have been, and you can `.delete` the filters at the end during the cleanup of your code, so no remaining clutter.

I don't know if either of these options are helpful, but they help me when trying to debug.